# Executing stored procedure based on table column value

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to return result from table based on value returned from another table column.

I am getting error when no data is found in `user_config` table. I want else part to execute instead.

````
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE valuefinders (
    in_soeid   IN VARCHAR2,
    out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
    group1 VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) := 'n';
    
BEGIN
    SELECT
        admin
    INTO group1
    FROM
        user_config
    WHERE
        soeid = in_soeid;

    IF ( group1 = 'y' ) THEN
        OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT
                                *
                            FROM
                                user_profile;

    ELSE
        OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT
                                *
                            FROM
                                user_request;

    END IF;

END valuefinders;```
````

Answer (score 2):

Handle the exception, somehow. The simplest option is to *do nothing*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE valuefinders (in_soeid    IN     VARCHAR2,
                                          out_cursor     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
   group1  VARCHAR2 (128 BYTE) := 'n';
BEGIN
   SELECT admin
     INTO group1
     FROM user_config
    WHERE soeid = in_soeid;

   IF (group1 = 'y')
   THEN
      OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM user_profile;
   ELSE
      OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM user_request;
   END IF;

EXCEPTION                     --> here
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      NULL;
END valuefinders;
```

---

If you want to do something else, then *just do it*:

```
EXCEPTION                                                             
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM user_request;
```

Comment: IF no data is found I have to return``ELSE
      OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM user_request;
   END IF;`` Can I do that

Comment: Sure; instead of NULL, use anything you want - including command you posted. See edited answer.

Comment: null at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CResultSetAccessor.getCursor(T4CResultSetAccessor.java:377)

I am getting this

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. Looks like something related to Java, and I don't speak Java.

Comment: But I am executing in sqldevleoper . Nothing to so with javas

Comment: Which SQL Developer version is it?

Comment: 21.4.3 is the version

Answer (score 2):

You can also nest exceptions in your code itself and take advantage of them.

This example shows that when the query on user_config raises a `NO_DATA_FOUND`, the variable `group1` is set to 'n' and the `else` block will be executed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE valuefinders (
    in_soeid   IN VARCHAR2,
    out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
    group1 VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) := 'n';
    
BEGIN
    BEGIN
      SELECT
        admin
      INTO group1
        FROM
          user_config
      WHERE
          soeid = in_soeid;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      group1 := 'n';
    END;

    IF ( group1 = 'y' ) THEN
        OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT
                                *
                            FROM
                                user_profile;
    ELSE
        OPEN out_cursor FOR SELECT
                                *
                            FROM
                                user_request;
    END IF;
END valuefinders;
```

Comment: null at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CResultSetAccessor.getCursor(T4CResultSetAccessor.java:377) I am geteting this error

Comment: This is a question about an oracle procedure. Try testing it out in a database IDE first (sql developer/sqlcl). only if it works, invoke it from java.

Comment: Yes I am executing this in sql developer there only this error